# How to solve the Jenkins' java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException on a remote node?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-agent

I created a sandbox project and want to run its declarative pipeline on a remote agent. I see, that the SSH connection between Jenkins and the agent is working. Jenkins can login on the remote machine (as user `ec2-user`). But the execution ends up in an exception: `java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /srv/www/htdocs/sandbox@tmp`.

The agent's root directory (where Jenkins creates the `remoting.jar`) is `/srv/www/htdocs/jenkins-agents`. The project's root directory (passed to the pipeline as `parameter`)  is `/srv/www/htdocs/sandbox`.  But Jenkins seems to try creating a new folder: `/srv/www/htdocs/sandbox@tmp`. And that cannot work, since the parent folder `/srv/www/htdocs` has some access restrictions and creating new directories in it is only allowed for `root` / `sudo users`.

**Why does Jenkins try to create this `@tmp` folder? How to avoid this behavior and get it working?**

---

**Addition info**

Executing of CLI commands is failing with this console output:

```
Started by user admin
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Produktivserver in /srv/www/htdocs/jenkins-agents/workspace/Sandbox
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] ws
Running in /srv/www/htdocs/sandbox
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // ws
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to Produktivserver
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1788)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:998)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1069)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1058)
        at hudson.FilePath.mkdirs(FilePath.java:1243)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.FileMonitoringTask$FileMonitoringController.<init>(FileMonitoringTask.java:198)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript$ShellController.<init>(BourneShellScript.java:337)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript$ShellController.<init>(BourneShellScript.java:326)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.launchWithCookie(BourneShellScript.java:178)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.FileMonitoringTask.launch(FileMonitoringTask.java:103)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.start(DurableTaskStep.java:317)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:286)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:179)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:163)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:157)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:161)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:165)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:135)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor187.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:400)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
        at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /srv/www/htdocs/sandbox@tmp
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:389)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:689)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:796)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:782)
    at hudson.FilePath.mkdirs(FilePath.java:3256)
    at hudson.FilePath.access$1300(FilePath.java:211)
    at hudson.FilePath$Mkdirs.invoke(FilePath.java:1251)
    at hudson.FilePath$Mkdirs.invoke(FilePath.java:1247)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:3069)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 4):

See [Jenkins Issue 52750](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-52750?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel) for more details.

Short summary: the `@tmp` directories are created by the `sh` step to record internal logs etc.

Jenkins assumes that the agent has full control of the directory it is running in.

The recommendation in that issue is to use a script that runs in a Jenkins workspace and deploys from there rather than trying to manipulate the target directory directly.

This will also allow you to handle file system errors/permissions.

Opening up permissions to world readable and world writable is a bad idea. Especially on a  directory that serves as a `DocumentRoot` for a web server.

Answer (score -4):

The solution is to make the parent of the workspace folder writable for Jenkins, or speaking more precisely, for the user, the Jenkins logs on the remote machine with. Here is a very simple (but insecure) way to do this (for the workspace folder `/path/parent/project` and the temp folder `/path/parent/project@tmp`):

```
$ chmod 777 /path/parent/
```

Comment: Please don't recommend people to open directories read-write for all users on a system.

Comment: @Bram In general you are right. But I mentioned, that it's insecure. And everyone is free to decide, whether to use an insecure solution or not.